# construct string from group dplyr

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr, shinytree

I have a large data frame and I am trying to construct a string based on groups within the data frame for displaying in [shinyTree](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shinyTree/README.html).

Here is an example of data:

```
dat <- data.frame("region" = c(paste("region", rep(1:3, each=4))),
              "area" = c(paste("area", rep(1:6, each=2))),
              "name" = c(paste("name",1:12)))
```

`shinyTree` requires that data is constructed in a string that looks like:

```
listString <- paste0("list('region 1' = list('area 1' = list('name 1'='', 'name 2'=''), 
                                         'area 2' = list('name 3'='', 'name 4'='')),
                       'region 2' = list('area 3' = list('name 5'='', 'name 6'=''), 
                                        'area 4' = list('name 7'='', 'name 8'='')),
                       'region 3' = list('area 5' = list('name 9'='', 'name 10'=''), 
                                        'area 6' = list('name 11'='', 'name 12'='')))")
```

Is there a way to construct this string using mutate and groups in dplyr? The `"list("` elements should be concatenated onto the 1st occurrence of each group.

I have tried nested `for` loops and nested `lapply()` functions with `compiler::cmpfun()` to speed it up, but this is proving to be too slow to construct. My data has 5 "levels" and ~3000 rows, and it takes ~30 seconds to process which is too slow for a shiny application.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution. The key is to use `summarise` and `str_c(collapse = )` to put the same hierarchy together, then `mutate` and `str_c` to add the additional `list(` calls and commas/spaces. Including `collapse=` means a character vector is turned into one of length one with the desired separator, making it possible to use with `summarise`. I'd try running this line by line to see how it comes together, alternately formatting then removing hierarchy. The final `[[` is just to make it a string format instead of a tibble. Since there are more levels in the real code, I wrapped the more repetitive `str_c` calls into `makelist` and `collapse` functions, to make it clearer what's happening when and more readable.

N.B. additional bonus is that `summarise` drops old variables for use and also removes grouping levels as we go, so we don't need any extra `group_by` or any `select` calls!

```r
library(tidyverse)
tbl <- tibble(
  "region" = c(paste("region", rep(1:3, each=4))),
  "area" = c(paste("area", rep(1:6, each=2))),
  "name" = c(paste("name",1:12))
)

makelist <- function(parent, child) str_c("'", parent, "' = list(", child, ")")
collapse <- function(level) str_c(level, collapse = ", ")

tbl %>%
  mutate(name = str_c("'", name, "'=''")) %>%
  group_by(region, area) %>%
  summarise(names = collapse(name)) %>%
  mutate(area = makelist(area, names)) %>%
  summarise(areas = collapse(area)) %>%
  mutate(region = makelist(region, areas)) %>%
  summarise(regions = collapse(region)) %>%
  mutate(liststr = str_c("list(", regions, ")")) %>%
  `[[`(1)
#> [1] "list('region 1' = list('area 1' = list('name 1'='', 'name 2'=''), 'area 2' = list('name 3'='', 'name 4'='')), 'region 2' = list('area 3' = list('name 5'='', 'name 6'=''), 'area 4' = list('name 7'='', 'name 8'='')), 'region 3' = list('area 5' = list('name 9'='', 'name 10'=''), 'area 6' = list('name 11'='', 'name 12'='')))"
```

Created on 2018-03-01 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: This is great, it reduced construction time from ~30 to 0.13 seconds! Many thanks.